# nilが結果として帰ってきた場合、その要素は最初から含めないようにするmapのようなメソッド

Tags: ruby

例えば、ある配列で、その要素が3の倍数のときのみ、その要素を掛け合わせた配列を新たに作りたいとします。具体的には`[3, 5, 9]`という配列が与えられた場合、期待している結果の配列が`[9, 81]`であるとします。このような判定を実現するためには、下のようなコードで出来ます:

```
[3, 5, 9].map { |x| x * x if x % 3 == 0 }.select { |x| !!x }
```

あるいは:

```
[3, 5, 9].select { |x| x % 3 == 0 }.map { |x| x * x }
```

といったように。

確かに上のように書くことは可能なのですが、個人的には、`map`の中で、帰ってくる結果が`nil`であるならば、それを配列の要素に含みたくないことを、`select`を使わずに表現したいと思っています。想定しているのは、以下の使い方に近い書き方です:

```
[3, 5, 9].map { |x| x * x if x % 3 == 0 }
```

もちろん、このままだと`nil`の要素も含まれてしまうので、上のような希望を達成することが出来ません。上記のような希望を実現できるメソッド、あるいは方法がもしあれば教えてください。

Comment: 回答になっていませんが、個人的には「[3, 5, 9].select { |x| x % 3 == 0 }.map { |x| x * x }」が一番意図が明確で良いと思います。

Comment: 参考になるかも : [List comprehension in Ruby - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310426/) .

Answer (score 5):

`map` は一対一対応の写像なので、その中で要素数を減らすのは難しいと思います。

```
[3, 5, 9].map { |x| x * x if x % 3 == 0 }.compact # 写像して nil 削除

[3, 5, 9].inject([]) { |ary, x| ary << x * x if x % 3 == 0; ary } # 畳み込み
```

とかいかがでしょう（他にもあるでしょうけど）。

Comment: 回答じゃ無いとおっしゃっている @Junichi-Ito さんのコメントの例（先に条件に合うものを選り抜いてから写像）が一番キレイだと感じます。ステップ数も少ないと思います。

Answer (score 3):

[singleton method Enumerator::Lazy.new](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Enumerator=3a=3aLazy/s/new.html)の例で挙げられている`filter_map`を定義するのはいかがでしょうか。

```ruby
module Enumerable
  def filter_map(&block)
    map(&block).compact
  end
end

class Enumerator::Lazy
  def filter_map
    Lazy.new(self) do |yielder, *values|
      result = yield *values
      yielder << result if result
    end
  end
end

(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.filter_map{|i| i*i if i.even?}.first(5)
    # => [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

ちなみに、この質問のようなメソッドが欲しいというFeature RequestがRubyのバグトラッキングシステムに出されています。
いいメソッドの名前があれば採用されてRubyに入って使えるようになると思うので、issueにコメントしてみるといいのではないでしょうか。

[Feature #5663: Combined map/select method - Ruby trunk - Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5663)

Answer (score 2):

そういうメソッドが欲しいのであればEnumerableモジュールに定義してしまえば作ることはできます。

```
module Enumerable
  def map_without_nil
    self.inject([]) do |arr, item|
      ret = yield item
      arr << ret unless ret.nil?
      arr
    end
  end
end

[3, 5, 9].map_without_nil {|i| i * i if i %  3 == 0} # => [9, 81]
```

ただし、この程度の話だと`select`を使うのより明らかに可読性は低下するので、おすすめはしません。

Answer (score 1):

```
[3, 5, 9].map { |x| x * x if x % 3 == 0 }.compact
```

これでは駄目でしょうか